# How to do pass a function as an argument of another function in R?

Tags: r

Consider the following example:

```
q1.func <- function(x) {
  num <- (cos(30.2 * x^(1/2)))^2 
  denom <- (x^0.7) * exp(0.9*x)

  num / denom
}

method1 <- function(n) {
  x <- runif(n,min = 0, max = 1.7)
  f <- q1.func(x)  

  (1.7) * sum((1/n) * f)
} 

draw.graph <- function() {
  n <- seq(1,1000,1)
  x <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(n)) {
    x <- append(x, method1(n[i]))
  }
  plot(n, x, type = "p", xlab = "N",ylab = "value" ,main = "method1 plot",col = "black")
}
```

My point is that I want to be able to perform: ***draw.graph(method1(n))***. But R wouldnt allow me to do that. I dont understand why is this happening??? My ultimate goal is that I would be able to pass method2 / method3 /.... as argument of draw.graph() function. But how??? Right now, I am only interested in solutions that allow me to pass method1 as an argument of the draw.graph function. Please dont ask me to write method1 WITHIN the draw.graph function, because I already know that it works. But I am more interested in passing method1 as an argument of the draw.graph function. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'll make a simpler example to illustrate the main point (there are other issues with the code you proposed).

```
fun1 = function(x) cos(x)
fun2 = function(x) sin(x)

# function where one argument is a function
wrapper = function(a = 2, fun = fun1){

  x = 1:10
  return(data.frame(x = x, y = a*fun(x)))
}

# testing behaviour
wrapper()
wrapper(fun = fun2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `draw.graph` function lacks an argument.
Why not simply use the return value of an function as argument of the next function?

```
draw.graph <- function(y) {
  plot(seq_along(y), y)
}

method1 <- function(n) {
  return(runif(n, min=0, max=1.7))
}

draw.graph(method1(100))
```

If you really need a function as argument you could try the following (please read `?match.fun`):

```
## stupid example
calc <- function(x, fun) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  return(fun(x))
}

calc(1:10, sum)
```

*EDIT:*
To fulfill the OP question/comments I add this specific example:

```
q1.func <- function(x) {
  num <- cos(30.2 * sqrt(x))^2
  denom <- x^0.7 * exp(0.9*x)
  return(num/denom)
}

method1 <- function(n) {
  x <- runif(n, min=0, max=1.7)
  return(1.7*sum(1/n*q1.func(x)))
}

draw.graph <- function(n, fun) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  y <- unlist(lapply(n, fun))
  plot(n, y)
}

draw.graph(1:1000, method1)
```

[image]

Comment: I notice that in your method, your method1 returns n values, and hence the draw.graph(y). How would you write your draw.graph(y) function if your method1 only generates 1 value, and you still want to pass the method1 function as an argument of draw.graph(y) function ??? Any suggestions ?

Comment: @ThomasNg: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. If `length(y)==1` only one point is drawn by `draw.graph`.

Comment: Because, if you look at the example code I wrote above, then you will notice that my method1 only generates 1 value,i.e. method1(3) and method1(10000) gives 2 different values. And right now, I am trying to plot method1(n) for n = 1,2,3,4,.....1000. And since I have other methods, i.e. method2, method3, method4, I am interested in knowing how can pass these functions that I called 'method' as an argument as my draw.graph() function.

Comment: @ThomasNg: I would use my second mentioned approach, please the find the new example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! Now, i understand more about the built in functions in R. ^^